# Does admissibility even matter in A* search if the heuristic function overestimates in a consistent manner?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, shortest-path, path-finding, a-star

What if the heuristic value of a node is, let’s say, actual cost of getting to goal x 10^5? The node with the least f cost is still popped from top of the priority queue.

for example: `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)`, `where h(n) = h1(n) x 10^5, where h1(n) = h1′(n)`

By definition, `h` here is the overestimate of the actual cost of getting to goal.

The reason I asked is because I could not really see the difference in performance of the algorithm with or without that constant factor. If then why should it matter that if h is admissible or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes:

1. In general: Admissibility is a **sufficient** condition for the optimality of A*, not a necessary one. Of course you might find an inadmissible heuristic exists that also returns an optimal result; it's just that A* doesn't provide any guarantees at that point.
2. In particular: "In a consistent manner" is vague, but if you consider "scaling" to fit this description, then note that **your scaling heuristic can fail** if the costs are not additive. Note that A* does *not* require the evaluation function to be f = g + h. While unintuitive at first glance, it is entirely possible and realistic for a problem to have other evaluation functions where it *doesn't even make sense* to add path costs (e.g. your costs might be probabilities).

Also note that "consistency" [has an entirely different meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) than the one you are using, so be careful when using that term. Under the usual definition, it is impossible for a consistent heuristic to be inadmissible.

Comment: The evaluation function for A* was defined as f(n) = g(n) + h(n) by Hart et al. and all the formal properties of the algorithm are based on it. Can you point me out to an example of a different evaluation function?

Comment: @FrankS101: Just do a search for `non-additive A* search` or something. You'll find links. [Here's one](https://cse.sc.edu/~mgv/csce580sp15/gradPres/580sp15BalabokhinKanapalaAStarNonAdditive.pdf#page=4). Note that what people recognize as a particular algorithm changes over time, e.g. if I remember correctly Dijkstra's algorithm was O(n²), but now it's assumed to be O(n log n) because there's no point imposing that as an extra restriction. Similarly, in A*, there's no need to stipulate that the costs be additive. You can find work on non-additive costs if you spend some time looking around.

Comment: @FrankS101: Just to clarify though, the cost functions obviously can't be completely arbitrary. I think the sufficient condition (in addition to the heuristic being admissible) was that the evaluation function be monotonically increasing, or you're essentially back in the land of negative edge weights. (Hopefully I'm not forgetting any necessary conditions; I'm not 100% sure.) Note that this is not the same condition as the heuristic being monotone (consistent).

Comment: @Mehrdad, "Admissibility is a sufficient condition for the optimality of A*, not a necessary one" and "Note that A* does not require the evaluation function to be f = g + h.  it is entirely possible and realistic for a problem to have other evaluation functions where it doesn't even make sense to add path costs "

BAM! I wish lots of lecture and text on A* (at least those I've read) could give very clear and straightforward answer like yours. Just clear my doubts in one post. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad, 

Can you elaborate on this one "but if you consider "scaling" to fit this description, then note that your scaling heuristic can fail if the costs are not additive"? A simple example might suffice. :)

Comment: @AungKhant: Yay! =) Hm, this might not be a satisfying counterexample since it's degenerate, but I think it's valid. Imagine if you have 2 edges (e1 and e2) between the same pair of vertices. Let's say your cost function is the probability that the travel time takes more than 6 minutes, and let's say e1 takes 9 minutes, and e2 takes 3 minutes. Let's say your heuristic multiplies the edge weights by 5. Both projected costs are 100%, so you traverse e1 first, and get a true cost of 100%. You incorrectly terminate because the projected cost of e2 is also 100%.

Comment: @AungKhant: Notice that this counterexample illustrates a problem with your question though. You *can't* rescale the *cost heuristic* here -- what does that even mean? (Why? Well, the *cost* of e2 is 0%, since it takes 3 minutes, which is less than 6. How would you "rescale" that probability to 100%? It doesn't even make sense.) So the real answer to your question is that *it wouldn't make sense*. But for the sake of argument, I assumed you'll scale the edge *weights*, but with the evaluation function being a nonlinear function of the weights. In that case, the example shows it still breaks.

Comment: @Mehrdad I improved my answer to tackle also the non-additive evaluation functions. IMHO if f = g + h is not used along with A*, I wouldn't call that A*, like those hundreds of algorithms based on A* that introduce or relax some constraints, solve similar problems, ...  IDA*, NAMOA*, LPA* or SMA* to name some examples.

Comment: @FrankS101: IDA*, etc. are names of **algorithms**, not names of problems. All of these algorithms have different names because the algorithms are different (AFAIK). Here the algorithm is A*; you're just running it on problems with a different regularity structure, but the algorithm is the same. If I develop binary search on a byte array and then run it on a string array, it's not like the name "binary search" becomes invalid just because the elements stopped being fixed-length. (And sure, I can give it a new name if I feel like it, but that doesn't make the original one suddenly wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

> What if the heuristic value of a node is, let’s say, actual cost of
>   getting to goal x 10^5?

Assuming a **perfect heuristic function** `h'(n)` is used, that is always equal to the remaining cost of the path from `n` to the closest goal node, if the heuristic function overestimates in a constant factor, then the same path will be found **regardless whether h is admissible or not**.

You can think of your example as a search with Dijkstra over a graph `G` where the costs of all arcs is multiplied by a constant factor, resulting in a new graph `G'`. Every shortest path in `G` is a shortest path in `G'`.

**Remark:** The answer would be the opposite if the heuristic overestimates but not in a constant factor for all nodes. In this case, **A* does not guarantee to find the optimal solution**.

**EDIT:** After reading @Mehrdad answer about generalizing the evaluation function to consider *non-additive costs*, from a purist point of view, I wouldn't say we are applying A* when costs are non-additive. **A* tackles the shortest path problem** and **assumes the costs are additive**, actually, **all its formal properties are based on that assumption**.

If the cost minimization criterion is generalized to include non-additive cost measures of solution paths, then IMHO we are talking about a different problem and therefore a different algorithm to solve it. In this case, I think the problem is called *NSAP* in literature (non-additive shortest path). An example of this can be found in this paper from **Rina Dechter** and **Judea Perl**: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.3090&rep=rep1&type=pdf (page 507) where they call the algorithm to solve the generalize problem **BF***, as they were studying the behavior of A* when both restrictions, additive cost measures and additive evaluation functions, are removed.

Comment: *"A different problem and therefore a different algorithm"* is weird reasoning. So you've never seen one algorithm solve multiple problems...? And isn't the additive case just a special case of the general not-assumed-to-be-additive case and hence solvable by the same algorithm? Also, the other sentence is obviously wrong too... given that A-star's properties can be proven to hold for other classes of costs, then it's obviously false that *"all of its formal properties are based on that assumption"*...